# PHPMailer: How to allow empty message body

Tags: phpmailer

I use PHPMailer to send email to a hp printer (ENVY 5644) which will print whatever the body contain and any attachments. This works, however, I would like to send it body-less since only the pdf attachment is of any interest. The body is just waste of paper. I know it is suggested in other treads that one could just put a single space character in the body and it will look empty but the printer will spit out an empty paper anyway. If I send an email from Thunderbird where I write nothing inside the body, not even a single space but only add an attachment, I do not wast any paper when printing. Only the attachment is printed.

I know, I can just put the paper back into the tray but it would be more nifty if I did not have to.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your looking for the flag `$mail->AllowEmpty = true;` - just check the [source code](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/src/PHPMailer.php#L410)

Comment: Also in [the docs](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#property_AllowEmpty).